# Error class AbstractDb not found

Tags: magento2, module, custom, resource-model

I'm following this guide :

> http://www.mage-world.com/blog/how-to-use-model-and-collection-in-magento-2.html

But at the end i get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb' not found in C:\wamp\www\eurecia-shop\app\code\Local\Providers\Model\Resource\providers.php on line 7

(I follow the tutorial, but i just change News by Providers, but it work the same)

this is my file where i get the error :

```
<?php
namespace Local\Providers\Model\Resource;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb;

class Providers extends AbstractDb

{
   /**
    * Define main table
    */
   protected function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('local_providers', 'id');
    }
}
```

I search on google, and no result for this. I'm new to magento, so i'm not really familiar with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb`

to `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`

Comment: Yes, thanks, i find it also after more search, i find a facebook post where someone ask, and one good comment on it xD